# Ionic IonRefresher render TypeError is not a function

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

Here is my code :

```js
class Calendar extends React.Component<{},State> {
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchCalendarApi(); //>> Working 
  }
  fetchCalendarApi(){
     //Doing my API call here
  }
  doRefresh(event: CustomEvent<RefresherEventDetail>){
    console.log('Begin async operation');
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      this.fetchCalendarApi(); //>> Not working
      event.detail.complete();
    }, 2000);
  }
 renderCal(){
    return (
      <IonPage>      
        <IonContent>  
          
          <IonRefresher slot="fixed" onIonRefresh={this.doRefresh}>
            <IonRefresherContent></IonRefresherContent>
          </IonRefresher>  
        </IonContent>    
     </IonPage>
    )
  }  
}
```

And I have this error when I actually use the pull refresh :

> TypeError: this.fetchCalendarApi is not a function at [...]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your doRefresh function to Arrow function:

```
doRefresh = (event: CustomEvent<RefresherEventDetail>) => {
    console.log('Begin async operation');
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      this.fetchCalendarApi(); //>> Not working
      event.detail.complete();
    }, 2000);
  }
```

The issue was because you were using the normal function and hence it was not able to get the fetchCalendarApi() function as it is not within the scope. By using the arrow function, this will refer to Class in which the method is defined.